# jQuery popup div is not staying open consistently (flicking)

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jquery so that when an image is hovered over, a popup div appears with data from an Ajax call.

I am testing in both IE and FF and the DIV is not playing nicely! Basically, it is closing for no reason (without moving the mouse). Sometimes its as if it has started the hoveroff event strait away.
I suppose flicking is the term you could use.

I've looked on Google but can't find any information that seems to be relevant. Anybody have an ideas why this would be? My code is below:

JS

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hover").hover(
  function(e){
    var ref = $(this).attr("wsref");
    var url = "https://site/_ref/shop/_base/order_status.php?action=getstatus&ref="+ref+"&sid="+Math.random();
    $("#status").show();
    var height = $(".status").height();
    var width = $(".status").width();
    leftVal = e.pageX - width -10 + "px";
    topVal = e.pageY - height -10 + "px";
    $("#status").css({left:leftVal,top:topVal});
    $("#status").html("<div id='loading'></div>").load(url);
  },
  function() {
    setTimeout('$("#status").hide()',1500);  
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<img class="hover" title="Order Received" name="Order Received" src="https://site/_ref/images/cart.png" wsref="002731"/>
```

Comment: You are giving showing the div on hover event. So ultimately it will flicker. If you should add if condition to return (not show again) if already showing in the hover event.

Comment: Sorry dont quite understand- are you saying that I need to add an if statement to only show it if it is not visibile, and to hide it if it is visible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
var isShowing;
isShowing=false;
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".hover").hover(
function(e){
if(!isShowing)
{
    var ref = $(this).attr("wsref");
   var url = "https://site/_ref/shop/_base/order_status.php?action=getstatus&    ref="+ref+"&sid="+Math.random();
    $("#status").show();
    var height = $(".status").height();
    var width = $(".status").width();
    $("#status").html("<div id='loading'></div>").load(url);
    isShowing=true;
}
leftVal = e.pageX - width -10 + "px";
topVal = e.pageY - height -10 + "px";
$("#status").css({left:leftVal,top:topVal});

},
function() {
setTimeout('$("#status").hide();',1500);  
});
});
```

After you hide make isShowing=false; you can also implement with out using isShowing variable, by looking into the display in style attribute of your status element.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you ARE hovering off the trigger image when the div opens. When the mouse is on the popup (because the popup is not a child of the trigger image) it counts as mouseOut on the trigger itself. There by closing the popup. Then the mouse is over the trigger again, causing it to reopen.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".hover").mouseover(function(e){
        var ref = $(this).attr("wsref");
        var url = "https://site/_ref/shop/_base/order_status.php?action=getstatus&ref="+ref+"&sid="+Math.random();
        $("#status").show();
        var height = $(".status").height();
        var width = $(".status").width();
        leftVal = e.pageX - width -10 + "px";
        topVal = e.pageY - height -10 + "px";
        $("#status").css({left:leftVal,top:topVal});
        $("#status").html("<div id='loading'></div>").load(url);
      });
    $("#status").mouseout(function() {
        setTimeout('$("#status").hide()',1500);  
      });
  });
```